Numerical comparison of two probability distribution functions
I have a dataset which satisfies Benford's law of anomalous numbers. However, I proved numerically that each sample in the dataset satisfies Benford's law but the probability density function of the first significant digit is far from constant. In particular, the probability that 1 is the most significant digit varies from 0.2 and 0.55 for different samples.
The question I'm trying to answer is: what is the minimum sample size required so that the probability density function of the first digit is close to the probability density function of the overall dataset?
I've tried Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Pearson's chi-squared test, but they both fail to distinguish between the probability density function of a sample and the overall dataset. Do you have any suggestions what tests can I try?
I found that the Kullback-Leibler divergence between the sample-level and the overall probability density function of the first digit decreases as the sample size increases. However, this would require defining an appropriate threshold which I'm trying to avoid.

Benford's law has a probability mass function rather than a density (it is only supported on the nine positive digits).   You cannot guarantee closeness in a sample.  So you need to explain what you mean by "close" and how confident you want to be of achieving this.
